# Your device is not compatible with this version, while installing from web and play store app

Tags: android, google-play, incompatibility

Before putting this issue in this forum, I have done lots of research to find out the actual cause of this but did n't get any satisfactory reason. I have uploaded a new build on play store around 6 months ago. Suddenly I came to know that this version of the app is not compatible for some devices. Below are the list of devices, which is incompatible for this version.

1. Nexus 5 (Android 5.0)
2. Samsung Note 3 (SM 9005) (Android 5.0)
3. Moto XT (Android 5.0)
4. One plus one (Android 5.0)

I requested to try to download the app through Play Store application and the web both, but in both the cases, it is not working. Whereas I've successfully installed on Moto G 3rdGen and Moto e 2ndGen (both on Android 5.0 and 5.1) and it's working perfectly fine.

Below is the content of app manifest file, please if anyone has the similar issue then kindly look at this and let me know what is wrong or what could be the possible reason for such kind of issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="22"
android:versionName="4.6" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.GlobalState"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<provider
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.activities.support.DealsSearchSuggestionProvider"
android:authorities="com.idefarms.android.dealslocator.searchProvider" />
<provider
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.activities.support.LocationSearchSuggestionProvider"
android:authorities="com.idefarms.android.dealslocator.locationSearchProvider" />

<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.HomeViewActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
android:value=".ListViewActivity" />
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.socialize.PrepareRequestTokenActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data
android:host="callback"
android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.ListViewActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
android:name="android.app.searchable"
android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.DealDetailActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.StoreLocationDealsActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<meta-data
android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
android:value=".ListViewActivity" />
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.ShowImage"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.MapViewActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
android:name="android.app.searchable"
android:resource="@xml/locationsearchable" />
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.LocationSearchActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
android:name="android.app.searchable"
android:resource="@xml/locationsearchable" />
</activity>

<meta-data
android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
android:value="@string/app_id" />

<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.SignInActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.SignUpActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.AddReview"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.EstablishmentActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.ReviewLogin"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.MerchantDashboard"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.NotificationActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.ManageSubscribedMerchants"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
<activity
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.PreferenceActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- Register Broadcast receiver -->

<receiver
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.notification.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

<category android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<!-- Register Service -->
<service android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.notification.GCMNotificationIntentService" />
<!-- Register Service for Notification Listener Service -->
<service
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.notification.NLService"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.notification.MuteNotificationService" />

<!-- Register Service for Remote syncing -->
<service android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.service.SubscribeMerchantService" />

<!-- Receiver for referral tracking -->
<receiver
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.receiver.ReferralTracking"
android:exported="true" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<!-- End of referral tracking receiver -->

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>

<permission
android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.ideafarms.android.dealchaat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<compatible-screens>

<!-- no small size screens -->


<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />

<!-- all large size screens -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />

<!-- all xlarge size screens -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />

<!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="213"
android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>

</manifest>
```

I appreciate of your help, please do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `<compatible-screens>` section from your Manifest file.

Comment: Check this. http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/03/07/make-sure-your-app-does-not-exclude-xxhdpi-screens/